# multiple records in audit table after updating a single records

Tags: sql, t-sql, triggers

I have a audit table "Audit_Table1" which tracks changes in "Table1". But the problem is that, the Stored Procedure updates the table at 3 different stages in the same SP. But the trigger is also fired thrice. So what can i do that the trigger is fired only once and captures all the changes.

Answer (score 0):

In your stored procedure, you can optionally disable the table trigger during the period of time you don't want it to fire.

```
DISABLE TRIGGER { [ schema_name . ] trigger_name [ ,...n ] | ALL }  
ON { object_name | DATABASE | ALL SERVER } [ ; ]
```

You can learn more here:

[DISABLE TRIGGER (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/disable-trigger-transact-sql)

It won't capture "all the changes", which I don't really understand.

If you don't want to capture certain parts, use the above.

Comment: I cannot disable the trigger. It should be enabled all the time but should be fired only once in the scope of a particular stored procedure

Comment: @Megha What is the definition on your trigger?  If it's INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE etc it's going to be called no matter what for each INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE that occurs on that table.

Comment: It is an after update trigger. I came accros something called as context_info in one of the triggers. But not sure how to use it in this case or its even useful.